# Computing Layer statistics using PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to develop a script for the Processing Toolbox which computes layer statistics, creates a style of upwards pointing triangles for higher than average elevation and downwards pointing red triangles for lower elevation based on statistics of a vector layer. This is how far I have gone:

```
##GeoGang=group
##GeoGeeK=name
##Input_vector_layer=vector
##Keep_attributes=boolean True
```

[image: GeoGeeKScript]
The output
[image: GeoGeeKScriptOutput]

Comment: There's a lot to do here - do you know how to get values from a layer's attributes? How to compute a mean? How to create a style?

Comment: Hi. I know how to get basic layer statistics for numeric fields by using the 'Analysis tools' tab but not using PyQGIS script. The rest I don't know. Thanks

Comment: Do you know Python? Have you looked at some of the PyQGIS tutorials? They'll explain the basics of reading attributes from a layer. You don't need a processing script to do this anyway - a categorical symbology will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it using the symbology. Use a categorical renderer, with an expression for the category which is `"stat" > mean("stat")` where the numeric attribute in your data is `stat`.

Classify, then edit the symbol for each category to be an up-pointing arrow, or a 180degree up-arrow rotated 180 degrees. Result is:

[image]

You can copy and paste this style to any other layer, edit the expression if the attribute name is different and re-classify. I don't see the point of making a processing script to do this.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman but unfortunately it is a requirement that I generate a processing script.